# Why I can't get the correct mask columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply, where-clause

For example, if I have a data frame

```
    x   f
0   0   [0, 1]
1   1   [3]
2   2   [2, 3, 4]
3   3   [3, 6]
4   4   [4, 5]
```

If I want to remove the rows which columns x doesn't in f columns, I tried with where and apply but I can't get the expected results. I got the below table and I want to know why row 0,2,3 are 0 instead of 1?

```
    x   f   mask
0   0   [0, 1]  0
1   1   [3] 0
2   2   [2, 3, 4]   0
3   3   [3, 6]  0
4   4   [4, 5]  0
```

Anyone knows why? And should I do to handle this number vs list case?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0,1,2,3,4],'f' :[[0,1],[3],[2,3,4],[3,6],[3,5]]}, index = [0,1,2,3,4])
df1['mask'] = np.where(df1.x.values in df1.f.values ,1,0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is necessary test values by pairs - solution with `in` in list comprehension:

```
df1['mask'] = np.where([a in b for a, b in df1[['x', 'f']].values],1,0)
```

Or with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and `axis=1`:

```
df1['mask'] = np.where(df1.apply(lambda x: x.x in x.f, axis=1),1,0)
```

---

```
print (df1)
   x          f  mask
0  0     [0, 1]     1
1  1        [3]     0
2  2  [2, 3, 4]     1
3  3     [3, 6]     1
4  4     [3, 5]     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Jezrael.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC row explode then use `isin`

```
pd.DataFrame(df1.f.tolist()).isin(df1.x).any(1).astype(int)
Out[10]: 
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    0
dtype: int32
df1['mask'] = pd.DataFrame(df1.f.tolist()).isin(df1.x).any(1).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, YOBEN_S. I am wondering why the sequence of isin() is reversed in your method? I thought it should be (df1.x).isin(df.f).

Comment: @ZhenYan after explode the row, we have df, we check each row of df to see whether it included in the row of series